# Why can't I execute a shell script using . ./test.sh?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I have a simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo test
```

I can execute script successfully as:

```
./test.sh
```

and

```
source ./test.sh
```

However, the following throws an error:

```
. ./test.sh
```

error:

```
.: Command not found.
```

What could be causing the error? This works on el capitan (which was an upgrade) but not on sierra. Did something change with the terminal or default shell in the past few major releases?

I'm running macOS 10.12.3 with the default terminal - this is a clean install and NOT an upgrade (upgrades hang onto previous shell settings).

Comment: Can you try it as just `. test.sh`, `POSIX` source recommends that way. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot

Comment: I still get .: command not found

Comment: @Inian: POSIX says "If file does not contain a <slash>, the shell shall use the search path specified by PATH to find the directory containing file.", which implies that you _must_ use path prefix `./` to source a file in the _current_ directory. `. test.sh` _shouldn't_ look in the current dir., (`bash` does, but `dash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` don't, in compliance with POSIX).

Comment: @mklement0: Fair point, duly noted!

Comment: `. file` does not execute `file`, it runs the commands from `file` in the same shell process that it is invoked from (assuming it is a shell supporting `.`) (It should mainly be used for things like manipulating variables in a shell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like **you've switched your default shell to something other than `bash`, probably `csh`**, where (a) `.` is not built-in command (only `source` is), and (b) even if it were, you couldn't load *Bash* code into the current session anyway.

To check what your default shell is, run `echo $SHELL`.

Run `chsh -s /bin/bash` to switch back to `bash` as your default shell.

Comment: The output now read /bin/bash . so it looks like the default shell was changed by one of the scripts my company uses to setup new macbooks - thanks a lot for your help. I will accept your answer.